# CallKit: how to differentiate between decline call and end connected call

Tags: ios, callkit

Suppose an app supports two calls at a time. the first call is connected and second call is coming in. one gets "end call & answer call",  "decline", "hold call and answer call" buttons.

In case of "end call & answer call", it means to end the connected call and answer the new call.
In case of "decline", it means to reject the incomming call.

In both cases the delegate

```
- (void)provider:(CXProvider *)provider performEndCallAction:(CXEndCallAction *)action
```

is triggered. Now, How do one should know which one of those calls to end, the incoming call or the call already connected? The `CXEndCallAction` doesnt state a reason for either "decline" nor "end-already-connected call"

does anyone have a solution?

Comment: There are so many different delegate methods, after those delegates this will be the final delegate. Make a note of other delegates getting triggered to make your decision.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found out that there is a transaction list delegate:

```
- (BOOL)provider:(CXProvider *)provider executeTransaction:(CXTransaction *)transaction
```

implementing this delegate will give enough information if there is a transaction that will trigger the other delegates such `CXSetHeldCallAction` or `CXEndCallAction`. so now I can decide what action is to trigger, and bypassing other delegates if necessary.

here is my code if anyone else is struggling:

```
- (BOOL)provider:(CXProvider *)provider executeTransaction:(CXTransaction *)transaction
{
NSLog(@"executeTransaction : %@", transaction.debugDescription);
BOOL callEnd = NO;
BOOL callHold= NO;
BOOL callAnswer = NO;

NSPredicate *filter = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"self isKindOfClass: %@", [CXEndCallAction class]];
NSArray *ends = [transaction.actions filteredArrayUsingPredicate:filter];
callEnd = [ends count] >= 1;

filter = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"self isKindOfClass: %@", [CXAnswerCallAction class]];
NSArray *answer = [transaction.actions filteredArrayUsingPredicate:filter];
callAnswer = [answer count] >= 1;

filter = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"self isKindOfClass: %@", [CXSetHeldCallAction class]];
NSArray *hold = [transaction.actions filteredArrayUsingPredicate:filter];
callHold = [hold count] >= 1;

if(callEnd && callAnswer)
{
    actionType = kCallKitEndAndAnswer;
    [[MyCallManager sharedManager] endPreviousCallAndAnswerNewCall:^(BOOL succeeded) {
        NSLog(@"end answered call: %@", succeeded ? @"yes" : @"No");
        CXEndCallAction *en = [ends firstObject];
        succeeded ? [en fulfill] : [en fail];

        CXAnswerCallAction *an= [answer firstObject];
        succeeded ? [an fulfill] : [an fail];

    }];
    return YES;
}
else if(callHold && callAnswer)
{
    actionType = kCallKitHoldAndAnswer;

    [[MyCallManager sharedManager] answerCall:^(BOOL succeeded) {
        NSLog(@"hold answered call: %@", succeeded ? @"yes" : @"No");
        CXSetHeldCallAction *ho = [hold firstObject];
        succeeded ? [ho fulfill] : [ho fail];

        CXAnswerCallAction *an= [answer firstObject];
        succeeded ? [an fulfill] : [an fail];
    }];
    return YES;
}
else if([hold count] == 2)
{
    [[MyCallManager sharedManager] swapCalls];
    usleep(25000);
    CXSetHeldCallAction * fi = [hold firstObject];
    CXSetHeldCallAction * la = [hold lastObject];
    [fi fulfill];
    [la fulfill];

    return YES;
}

return NO;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to access the callUUID member of the CXEndCallAction.

The transaction is called on the right object so you just terminate the call matching the UUID transmitted. That implies you must add support for UUIDs to your own calls object model.

Answer (score 0):

You can use enum and "isMemberOfClass".

In providerDelegate.h

```
 // Call Modes.
 typedef NS_ENUM(NSUInteger, CallMode) {
     kUnknownMode = 0,
     kEndAndAnswerMode = 1,
     kHoldAndAnswerMode = 2
};
```

In providerDelegate.m

```
@property(nonatomic, assign) CallMode mode;
```

And add below code to get every transaction.

```
- (BOOL)provider:(CXProvider *)provider executeTransaction:(CXTransaction *)transaction {

    NSLog(@"Provider execute transaction");

    BOOL callEnd = NO;
    BOOL callHold= NO;
    BOOL callAnswer = NO;

    NSPredicate *filter = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"self isMemberOfClass: %@", [CXEndCallAction class]];
    NSArray<CXEndCallAction *> *ends = [transaction.actions filteredArrayUsingPredicate:filter];
    callEnd = [ends count] >= 1;

    filter = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"self isMemberOfClass: %@", [CXAnswerCallAction class]];
    NSArray<CXAnswerCallAction *> *answers = [transaction.actions filteredArrayUsingPredicate:filter];
    callAnswer = [answers count] >= 1;

    filter = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"self isMemberOfClass: %@", [CXSetHeldCallAction class]];
    NSArray<CXSetHeldCallAction *> *holds = [transaction.actions filteredArrayUsingPredicate:filter];
    callHold = [holds count] >= 1;

    if(callEnd && callAnswer) {
        _mode = kEndAndAnswerMode;
    } else if(callHold && callAnswer) {
        _mode = kHoldAndAnswerMode;
    } else {
        _mode = kUnknownMode;
    }

    return NO;
}
```